# Show that if there are 101 people of different heights standing in a line

Tags: extremal-combinatorics

Show that if there are 101 people of different heights
standing in a line, it is possible to ﬁnd 11 people in the
order they are standing in the line with heights that are
either increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Can people only have integer heights?

Comment: That shouldn't matter, I don't think? Since all that matters is their ordering, you can just reduce it to the case where the heights are a permutation of $1$ through $101$.

Comment: Also, this is a special case of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316006/creating-a-sequence-that-does-not-have-an-increasing-or-a-decreasing-sequence-of).

Comment: @HenrySwanson I assumed it would be eleven people in a row. But there's no reason to think that's required.

Comment: Well, it's false if the $11$ people have to be next to each other, consider $1,101,2,100,3,99,\cdots$. So I think the OP is looking for any subsequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a partial order on the set of people by stipulating that $x\lt y$ means that person $x$ is shorter than $y$ **and** is standing behind $y$. The question asks us to show that this partially ordered set of size $101$ contains either a chain or an antichain of size $11$. The simpler way to do this is to observe that a partially ordered set, which contains no $11$-element chain, is the union of $10$ antichains, one of which must contain more than $10$ elements by the pigeonhole principle. The fancier alternative is to quote [Dilworth's chain decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem): if there is no $11$-element antichain, then the poset is the union of $10$ chains, etc.

Comment: Nice proof, it took me a few minutes to work out that the antichains actually are what we want them to be.

Answer (score 5):

This is a special case of the [Erdős-Szekeres theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s-Szekeres_theorem) with $r = s = 11$.

Here is a proof for this special case. I am assuming that no two people have the same height. For the $i$:th person $P_i$ in the line, we let $x_i$ be the length of the longest sequence of people *behind* $P_i$ which are increasing in height (including $P_i$). We let $y_i$ be the length of the longest sequence of people *in front of* $P_i$ which are decreasing in height (including $P_i$).

Now, for $i < j$ we have $(x_i,y_i) \neq (x_j,y_j)$. This follows from the fact that if $P_i$ is shorter than $P_j$ then the longest sequence of increasing heights ending at $P_i$ can be used to build a longer sequence ending at $P_j$, so $x_i < x_j$, or if $P_i$ is taller than $P_j$, the longest sequence of decreasing heights after $P_j$ can be used to build a longer sequence of decreasing heights after $P_i$, so $y_i > y_j$.

Thus, we have 101 different tuples of numbers. We can place these into a grid of $101 \times 101$ pigeonholes, and we place $(x_i,y_i)$ into the pigeonhole at $(x_i,y_i)$. Each pigeonhole gets at most one tuple, since $(x_i,y_i) \neq (x_j, y_j)$. But we see that we have more tuples than fit into a $10 \times 10$ grid of pigeonholes, meaning that at least one tuple has $x_i > 10$ or $y_i > 10$, meaning that there is a subsequence of at least 11 people with decreasing or increasing heights.

Answer (score 3):

This is a straight-forward application to the pigeonhole principle. In fact a more general statement holds:

> If $a_1,\ldots,a_{n^2+1}$ is a sequence of $n^2+1$ real numbers then
>   it must contain either an increasing or a decreasing subsequence of
>   length $n+1$.

For a proof see for example [this](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pigeonhole/seq.shtml#solution).