# If $n^2+1$ people are lined up, there are $n+1$ whose heights are increasing or decreasing

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Suppose $n^2 +1$ people are lined up shoulder to shoulder is a straight line. Then it is always possible to choose $n+1$ of the people to take one step forward so that going from left to right their heights are increasing (or decreasing).

I know my teacher wants us to use the pigeonhole principle on this and so you know its not a difficult proofs class, but please explain the calculus if your using summation as it's my hardest thing to grasp, my teacher forgets to show us the calculus or explain it sometimes.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/316019  http://math.stackexchange.com/q/619088 http://math.stackexchange.com/q/587961

Comment: And also see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/591411/11619) for an explanation that $n^2+1$ is the minimum.